# How can I investigates whether already running a program called /root/dodo/dodo

Tags: linux

How can I investigates whether already running a program called /root/dodo/dodo?
**But I need to run a scan directly from the program, which tests.**
Thank you...

```
file /root/todo/todo

#!/bin/bash
if [ check run program /root/todo/todo ]
then
  exit
else
  #continued
fi
```

Comment: Can you give some more information? Do you need to check programmatically whether process `/root/dodo/dodo` is running? If yes, then what `language` are you using?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry! Language is bash/shell. Thank

Answer (score 1):

you can check the process and see if there is a name like you indicated:

```
$ ps aux | grep "/root/dodo/dodo"
```

if you need to do test inside a bash script,

```
ps aux | grep -v "grep" | grep -q "/root/dodo/dodo"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   # do stuff if it is running
else
   # do stuff if it is not running
fi
```

Comment: but the control is started from the / root / todo / todo. ps aux ... I always give the program runs

Comment: @petr I cannot understand your comments, but anyhow, above is an example code to do test

Comment: Thank, the result is still do stuff if it is running :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether a program called /root/dodo/dodo is already running or not at the moment, use the following:

```
ps eaf | grep /root/dodo/dodo
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to write a shell script which ensures that there is only one single instance (process) running it.

Then see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1715137/841108) and consider using `lockfile(1)`

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to check whether one or more running processes match a string is `pgrep`. *Never* use `ps | grep`.

```
if pgrep bash >/dev/null; then 
   echo "found a bash process"
else 
   echo "didn't find a bash process"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you may need to scan all running bash processes and check what script they run (at least in my bash this is always filedescriptor 255)..

the following may be a bit fragile in point of portability and longtime availability but it may fix your problem for now..

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i running

cmd=$(readlink -f "${0}")

while true ; do
    running=0
    pids=( $(pidof bash) )

    for p in "${pids[@]}" ; do
        script=$(readlink -f /proc/${p}/fd/255 2>/dev/null)
        if [ "${script}" = "${cmd}" ] ; then
            running+=1
        fi
    done

    echo "running ${running} times.. this is $$.."
    sleep 1
done
```

Exit logic is not implemented.. it just counts number of running processes in a loop.. 8) should be easy to adopt..

This introduces some race conditions (as every solution may do) since if you get 2 running instances they both may be checking and deciding to exit because they are already running.. 8)

the readlinks are required to resolve any symlinks.. this may be needed if the script is started by another name (symlink with another name to itself)..

Actually I would solve this issue by file locking and/or by creating a pid file..